# Creating sql scripts to create table inside postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker

I am trying to create a postgres container which executes .sql script while launching up. The CREATE TABLE script is working if only column names are provided. However When I add CONSTRAINT in the script, it doesn't execute in container and tables won't get created.

**sql script below:**

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_APP_DB"."ACCESS_MASTER"
(
    "ACCESS_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "ROLE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "RESOURCE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "CAN_ACCESS" character(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
    "CAN_READ" character(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
    "CAN_WRITE" character(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
    "CAN_DELETE" character(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
    "CAN_EXECUTE" character(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
    CONSTRAINT "ACCESS_MASTER_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ACCESS_ID"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_RESOURCE" FOREIGN KEY ("RESOURCE_ID")
        REFERENCES "MY_APP_DB"."IMC_RESOURCE_MASTER" ("RESOURCE_ID") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_ROLE_MASTER_ACCESS_MASTER" FOREIGN KEY ("ROLE_ID")
        REFERENCES "MY_APP_DB"."ROLE_MASTER" ("ROLE_ID") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT FK_AM_AM FOREIGN KEY ("ACCESS_ID")
        REFERENCES "MY_APP_DB"."ACCESS_MASTER" ("ACCESS_ID") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT FK_ROLE_MASTER_ACCESS_MASTER FOREIGN KEY ("ROLE_ID")
        REFERENCES "MY_APP_DB"."ROLE_MASTER" ("ROLE_ID") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT FK_RM_RES_MAS FOREIGN KEY ("RESOURCE_ID")
        REFERENCES "MY_APP_DB"."IMC_RESOURCE_MASTER" ("RESOURCE_ID") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

It executes till CAN EXECUTE Column but not after that. Why is this so? What's wrong.? Please help

Comment: can you please share the error message you get from postgres

Comment: No error messages. It doesn't create the table at all if I use the entire script above. But If I use the lines till CAN EXECUTE and remove remaining, table gets created.

Comment: Somethings going wrong from CONSTRAINT row

Comment: Perhaps the error message is going to a log file? https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/11/12/dear-postgresql-where-are-my-logs

Comment: it works unless the references objects are in place. see dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=675682f6883181dd4dd3561f1fd1044b .. might help you

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 You mean it **doesn't** work unless the referenced objects exist, right?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Yes that is what I mean

Comment: @SujitMohanty, hint helped. Please post it as answer. will accept. Thanks

Comment: @Ranjith: I did.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works unless the references objects are in place, See the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=675682f6883181dd4dd3561f1fd1044b) might help.